# I have two entity they are connected by one to one mapping i want to save only one entity data and get the existing id of another entity and map

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have two entity they are connected by OnetoOne mapping i want to save only one entity data and get the data of another entity and store its primary key in our table how can i do please help?

```
@Entity
class Vehicle
{
@Id
@GeneratedValue(statergy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int id;

@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name="device_id",referencedColumnName = "id")
private Device deviceId;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean you want to save a Vehicle in the database and have the Foreign Key be not null (meaning the Vehicle you want to save in DB, will have a Device mapped to it), you can do that by:
finding the Device in the database, then create a new Vehicle object (leave id as null, bcs it will be auto generated when you save it in the db).
After that just use a setter to set the Device into the Vehicle.
(ex: vehicle.setDevice(**theDeviceObjecYouGotFromTheDatabase**)).

A way to implement it would be this:
Note: A VehicleDTO would be recommended, but I simplified it. Also I used some weird names for the objects just to be more clear.

```
public Vehicle saveVehicle(Vehicle vehicleToBeSaved, Long deviceId) {
    Device deviceThatWasInDb = this.deviceRepository.findById(deviceId)
            .orElseThrow(() -> {
                throw new EntityNotFoundException("Device with this id was not in the db");
            });
    // assuming that the vehicleToBeSaved has null id, you just need to use a setter to set the device field
    vehicleToBeSaved.setDevice(deviceThatWasInDb);

    Vehicle vehicleAfterBeingSaved = this.vehicleRepository.save(vehicleToBeSaved);

    return vehicleAfterBeingSaved;
}
```

I assumed that we are in Service layer, and you already have created the VehicleRepository & DeviceRepository.

Hope this helps.

Comment: How can we do through coding can you please Explain because i tried my best but it is not happening we have already the device details in the database how it will map  antomatically we have new vehicle we have to map that device to the vehicle ?

Comment: ok, i'lll edit the answer with an example. I will asume that you get the Vehicle object and the ID of the device you want to map to this vehicle, as arguments.

Comment: thanks a lot its helpful i want to know one more thing the device Id come into Requestbody or RequestParam

Comment: It depends on how you want to structure your endpoints. In the example i assumed it was a request parameter(smth like: POST /{deviceId}/vehicle), however you can make it so that it comes from the Request Body. Suppose you have the class VehicleCreateRequest which has fields for the new vehicle entity and a field for the id of the Device that you want this new Vehicle to have. The frontend will send this class as a request, and in the service layer you extract the fields into a Vehicle object and also get the Device Id.

Comment: thanks its to much helpful for me thanks a lot